# Find nearby restaurants using MKLocalSearch/MapKit?

Tags: swift, mapkit

I am using an MKLocalSearch to show nearby locations using Apple Maps and cannot find a way to filter for a specific type of place (restaurant/bar/eatery in my case). Is there a way to filter the results similarly to how Apple Maps App shows restaurants with an icon? I am currently filtering out empty subtitles and search nearby subtitles but this is not nearly specific enough. Code for the MKLocalSearch:

```
extension LocationService: MKLocalSearchCompleterDelegate {

    func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
        self.searchResults = completer.results.filter({ $0.subtitle != "Search Nearby" && $0.subtitle != "" })
        self.status = completer.results.isEmpty ? .noResults : .result
    }

    func completer(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        self.status = .error(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking about the wrong place in the search. You need to set the search request's `pointOfInterestFilter` *before* doing the search.